# Include file with prefixed labels

Tags: cross-referencing, external-files, include

Say I `\include` `A.tex` and `B.tex` in `main.tex`. Say `A.tex` has something labeled in it, `\label{a}`. Then I can just reference this in `B.tex` as `\ref{a}` without any problem. I don't want to be able to do this: I would like to cross reference between files with prefixes as one can do using the **xr** package.

Namely, by default I don't want any labels from `A.tex` imported into `B.tex` (so that I can safely define a `\label{a}` in `B.tex` as well). But then if I call some command, analogous to `\externaldocument[A-]{A}`, I should be able to reference the thing in `A.tex` by `\ref{A-a}`.

How can/should I implement this kind of document structure?

Comment: Why don't you change all labels in A.tex from `\label{` to `\label{A-`? If you tell us, which editor, probably somebody will come up with a regular expression to change e.g. `\label{sec:section-1}` to `\label{sec:A-section-1}` and accordingly with "fig:", "tab:" and so on.

Comment: Yeah that would be a solution, but I'd prefer not to have to do anything manually (even if it's just a regex replace).